# How can I know in which direction 2 balls will go in billiard game?

Tags: collision-detection

When a ball is struck, how can we know in which direction both balls will go when ball is struck? I know the angle at which the ball strikes the other ball matters, but how can we calculate that angle?

I've seen some of the videos to get started with elastic collision. Here is the link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZOkrCQRVWM

But it assumes that we know the angle at which the ball strikes other ball. May be I am asking too basic question but I am not a Physics guy so I need to understand how to calculate the angle.

Thanks in advance :)